# Como utilizar sentencias de decisión en OCL

Tags: mysql

Necesito hacer que me de Error cuando en las instancias dinámicas pongo EsHerencia = true y cardinalidad de 1 a M o de 1 a 1. Y necesito que no me de Error cuando EsHerencia = false y cardinalidad = 0.. pero al parecer no logro hacer que me funcionen las condiciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. Además, pon las etiquetas que estén relacionadas a la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.